# Why is the Chinese ABC song different?

Tags: history, copyright

Why is the Chinese ABC song different to most of the rest of the world?

The traditional song in all Western European countries has a fast LMNOP and whole song similar to this:

[image]

The second half has more minor variations across languages, generally to fit in the syllables of their words for W and Y, but the tune remains pretty much the same.

The song that most European countries are taught to learn the English alphabet is this one with a fast LMNOP.

But the Chinese song taught for the English alphabet already begins to differ at L:

[image]

And the ending is pretty different too.

Who wrote the Chinese one? Why do they use it instead of the mainstream one?